# Word for the thing that's fixed on the wall and holds a (fire) torch in stories set in the distant past

Tags: single-word-requests

What do you call the thing that holds a torch? They're used a lot in old movies. They're fixed on walls and used for holding the fire (torch).

Here's an image of what I'm talking about but it's not quite the same as the one used for holding the torch:

[image: The thing that holds torch/light]

Here's the torch I'm referring to:

[image]

What's the name of the thing that is fixed on a wall and holds this torch?

Comment: A cage. In this case a Nicholas cage.

Comment: As a more general term you could call it a _bracket_ (perhaps _torch bracket_.)

Answer (score 75, accepted):

It is called a **sconce**. [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/sconce) says

> **sconce**
> NOUN
>
> **1** A candle holder that is attached to a wall with an ornamental bracket.

Here is a  picture of one.

[image]

<sub>*Image from pinterest.com*</sub>

Comment: I think, technically, it's a cgi rendering, rather than a picture.

Comment: @Acccumulation I think, technically, a CGI rendering *is* a picture, though you could say it is not a photograph.

Comment: @Acccumulation good spot, but I could hardly post a *real* sconce... underneath the attribution says  *Image*.

Comment: @WeatherVane But maybe a photograph of a real sconce?

Comment: Another possibility is a cresset: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cresset

Comment: @jamesqf a cresset is a fire cup or basket, not a torch holder. It contains the fire itself.

Comment: So to summarise, a *sconce* is a mounted bracket for a candle or torch, a *cresset* is such a bracket that holds the burning material directly, and a *brazier* also holds fuel directly, but is freestanding or hanging.

Comment: @JonPurdy You reminded me of my favorite obscure Japanese word.  Matabi: to warm one's loins by standing astride a brazier

Comment: Sconce is surely correct, but I'm weirded out by the fact that neither your citation nor @JasonBassford's Merriam-Webster quote actually mentions torches, only candles (which I think of as a very minor use case, based on my personal reading habits, heh.) Anyone got a cite that *directly* answers the question, rather than depending on readers taking our word for it that it applies to torches as well?

Comment: @SirTechSpec the linked Lexico definition does give the example usage *No corner of the room had been neglected - even the wooden torches burning in the wall sconces had been carved with intricate flowers and leaves.* Also ***1.1** A flaming torch or candle secured in a sconce*, so there it is, in the dictionary.

Answer (score 16):

It's a [**sconce**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sconce):

> [Merriam-Webster]
> 1 : a bracket candlestick or group of candlesticks
> *also* : an electric light fixture patterned on a candle sconce

Thanks to some comments, and after rereading the question, the second picture in the question is simply showing an example of torches that would have been pulled out of sconces in the wall.

Comment: I wonder if there is a separate word for the hand-held version. A sconce sounds very much much like a bracket to me. It is the fixture in which the torch is *esconced*

Comment: I thought the second picture was just an example of the sort of torch the OP had in mind, which could be placed into a sconce on the wall. Characters in that sort of movie often pull a torch out of a (wall) sconce to carry into a tunnel or whatever.

Comment: @nnnnnn Yes, I think you're right. After reading the question again, that does indeed seem to be why the second picture (from *National Treasure*) was used.

Comment: @nnnnnn I'm sure that you are correct. If you want a fancier word for the torch it can be called a [flambeau](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/flambeau). The Merriam Webster entry behind the link defines it as "flaming torch". Calling it a "flambeau" has the advantage in BrEng that it distinguishes it from the modern electric torch which is more commonly called a "flashlight" in the US.

Comment: @BoldBen: We Brits know what a torch is. A flambeau, on the other hand...

Comment: @TonyK A [Flambeau](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flambeau_(character)), on the other hand... is the alias of a criminal from G.K.Chesterton's _Father Brown_ novels.

Comment: @TripeHound Very true, but I think Chesterton probably knew that a flambeau was a torch, not only that but Fr Brown turned him round and made him a detective. An interesting aside is that the ballad [Six Dukes Went A fishing](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Six_Dukes_Went_a-Fishing) describes a funeral with noblemen in attendance and the lines "Black was their mourning,
And white were the wands,
And so yellow were the flamboys,
That they carried in their hands" _flamboys_ being another word for flambeaux.

Comment: @boldben This is a good answer, but the comment thread lacks flare...

Comment: @chasly-reinstateMonica is the hand held version not simply the torch?

Comment: @Conrado - I hope you're not trying to start  a *flame* war!!!

Answer (score 5):

As others have noted, **sconce** is more common, and more specifically referring to something holding a long piece of wood.

However, a **cresset** can also be used to hold a torch.  But it more commonly holds either liquid flammables or pieces of loose wood or coals.

cresset

in American English

(ˈkrɛsɪt  )

NOUN

a metal container for burning oil, wood, etc., fastened as to a pole or wall and used as a torch or lantern

https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/cresset

Comment: As noted in the comments to WeatherVanes answer, and as described in the text you quoted, the cresset is a thing that can be held by a sconce. From there it may be and taken and carried a portable light source, as shown in the OP's second image.